# How to resume a pytorch training of a deep learning model while training stopped due to power issues or some other interrpts

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, resuming-training

Actually i am training a deep learning model and want to save checkpoint of the model but its stopped when power is off then i have to start from that point from which its interrupted like 10 epoches completed and want to resume/start again from epoch 11 with that parameters

Answer (score 1):

In PyTorch, you can resume from a specific point by using `epoch` key from the `checkpoint` dictionary as follows:

```
# Load model checkpoint
checkpoint = torch.load("checkpoint.pth")
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
epoch = checkpoint['epoch']

# Resume training from a specific epoch
for epoch in range(epoch + 1, num_epochs):
    ...
```

Comment: I would also save/load the optimizer's state directory.


optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state'])